# How to insert spaces vertically of a list in excel

Tags: excel, insert, vertical-alignment, space

What commands would I use to select all state names and places 5 spaces in between them vertically. So if a1 contains Alabama a7 should read Alaska.

[image]

Comment: You will need to write vba that Loops the range and does the inserts.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, will it be right to share a code, created one, since OP has not tried anything

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya that would be up to you.  I personally do not write code for free.  I will gladly help overcome specific problems with existing code, but write from scratch, no.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, alright, but I had done previously for my requirement, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(ROW()/6=ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/6,0),INDEX(A:A,ROW()/6),"")
```

To generate a new column, then copy and paste special the values where you want them